# C# Pragma to suppress break on thrown error

Tags: c#, exception, pragma

First off I run my applications with exceptions thrown on any error (handled or not).

Second I am using a `TypeConverter` to convert from a user input string to the actual object.

Third `TypeConverter` offers no `TryConvert` method so I'm stuck using exceptions for validation, using this rather ugly bit of code here:

```
try
{
    this._newValue = null;
#pragma Magic_SuppressBreakErrorThrown  System.Exception
    this._newValue = this.Converter.ConvertFromString(this._textBox.Text);
#pragma Magic_ResumeBreakErrorThrown  System.Exception
    this.HideInvalidNotification();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    if (exception.InnerException is FormatException)
    {
        this.ShowInvalidNotification(this._textBox.Text);
    }
    else
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I'm finding it rather distracting to have VS break execution every-time I type the `-` of `-1`, or some other invalid character. I could use something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111280/general-type-conversion-without-risking-exceptions) but not all the types I'm converting to have a `TryParse` method either.

I'm hoping there may be some way to disable breaking for the section of code within the `try` without changing my exception settings.

Comment: This is a debugger option, not a compiler option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am not sure I follow your question entirely, but if you want to disable VS break on specific exceptions you can customize this using the Exceptions dialog (ctrl-alt-e). Open the Common Language Runtime Exceptions tree and drill down to the specific exception and turn that off. FormatException is located under System. That way VS will break on all managed exceptions except FormatException.

Comment: That is indeed the effect I'm looking for, unfortunately it throws a System.Exception not FormatException. I was hoping to still be able to break on all, except if it occurs within an explicitly defined region of code (see edit).

Comment: But that turns off all throws of that kind of exception.. What if your program is potentially throwing FormatException in maybe 100 places, and you add a try/catch for the first place, but that's in a loop of 1000 items, before it gets thrown somewhere else. I guess the OP wants to say "I want to break on FormatException thrown EXCEPT when this ...  block of code throws it"

Answer (score 18):

Put the try/catch in it's own method and set this attribute on the method:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode]
```

The debugger will not stop inside that method (even for breakpoints).  And when the method is finished, the exception has already been handled so it doesn't break at that point either.

Comment: Good call, this solved my problem (I have hundreds of palces ArgumentNull may throw, and one is very often, two are very obscure. By making this attribute on the place where it throws often (I handled it there already), I can find the other places it is throwing when the entire logic loop has a wrapping handler, thanks!

Comment: Note that this does not work for statements invoked through a LINQ query, which the debugger will step in to anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Under the Debug -> Exceptions menu you can turn of breaking for any particular exception type.

Comment: But what if you want a logic of "I want to break on FormatException thrown EXCEPT when this block of code throws it, because I already handled it there so I don't care - I want one of the other places it's throwing"

Comment: VS 2017 added conditions to the exception window. I haven't used it so I don't know if it would handle the case you're talking about but it may be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer, but you could create a method that does a sanity check on the string values, before you attempt to use the TypeConverter, and then apply the Conditional("DEBUG") attribute to it - so the production code goes ahead and uses the TypeConverter (and catches all failing cases) whilst while debugging, your common errors are picked up and avoided before hitting the TypeConverter.

By applying the conditional, you avoid this code being used at all in the release version of your code - it's just there to catch the common errors which are currently creeping in.