# ErrorProvider - Input string was not in a recognized format C#

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, data-binding, entity-framework-5

I'm currently work with Entity Framework 5.0 and WinForms.  What I'd like to do is set-up validation on my POCO classes so that when I databind them to form fields I'd like to display UI validation errors via an ErrorProvider.  I have set up a base "ValidationEntity" class that implements the IDataErrorInfo interface with some simple validation methods for my child classes to call.  For the most part, validating the field length, range, etc.. seem to be working fine displaying the errors to the user via the ErrorProvider.

However, I seem to have ran into an issue with the "ValidateRequiredField" method.  If I have a class that has a non-nullable integer field and the user happens to remove this value on the form the ErrorProvider does show a message to the end-user, but the message is "Input string was not in a recognized format".  Now I assume this is because the form, being bound to an integer field, is attempting to convert the empty text into an integer and a conversion error is occurring prior to the value being sent to the POCO class property.  My question is, what would the best approach to solve this be?

I'm guessing that I may have to implement the Validating methods of the TextBox controls inside the form, catch the empty/null entry, and set the appropriate error message on the error provider.  However, I was hoping on a way to let the class handle the empty/null value and set the error inside the POCO class so that it propagates to the UI.  Originally I had thought of creating a custom TypeConverter (e.g. RequiredIntTypeConverter) but ran into issues since I'm inheriting from the ValidationEntity class and couldn't think of a good way of adding to the errors.

Below is a sample from the ValidationEntity class as well as a snippet from the Company class.

**ValidationEntity.cs**

```
public class ValidationEntity : IDataErrorInfo
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, List<string>> errors = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    string IDataErrorInfo.Error
    {
        get { return string.Empty; }
    }

    string IDataErrorInfo.this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            return (!errors.ContainsKey(propertyName) ? null : String.Join(Environment.NewLine, errors[propertyName]));
        }
    }

    public void AddError(string propertyName, string error, bool isWarning)
    {
        if (!errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            errors[propertyName] = new List<string>();
        }

        if (!errors[propertyName].Contains(error))
        {
            if (isWarning)
            {
                errors[propertyName].Add(error);
            }
            else
            {
                errors[propertyName].Insert(0, error);
            }
        }
    }

    public void RemoveError(string propertyName, string error)
    {
        if (errors.ContainsKey(propertyName) &&
            errors[propertyName].Contains(error))
        {
            errors[propertyName].Remove(error);
            if (errors[propertyName].Count == 0)
            {
                errors.Remove(propertyName);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ValidateFieldLength(string propertyName, string value, int maxLength)
    {
        string errorMessage = string.Format("Text entered exceeds max length of {0} characters", maxLength);

        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value.Length > maxLength)
            {
                if (!errors.ContainsKey(propertyName))
                {
                    AddError(propertyName, errorMessage, false);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                RemoveError(propertyName, errorMessage);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            RemoveError(propertyName, errorMessage);
        }
    }

    public void ValidateRequiredField(string propertyName, string value)
    {
        string errorMessage = string.Format("{0} is required.", propertyName);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            AddError(propertyName, errorMessage, false);
        }
        else
        {
            RemoveError(propertyName, errorMessage);
        }
    }        
}
```

**Company.cs**

```
public class Company : ValidationEntity
{
   private int companyID;
   private string companyName;

   public int CompanyID 
   {
     get { return this.companyID; }
     set 
     {
       OnCompanyIdChanging(value.ToString());
       this.companyID = value;
     } 
   }
   public string CompanyName
   {
     get { return this.companyName; }
     set 
     {
       OnCompanyNameChanging(value);
       this.companyName = value; 
     }
   }

   private void OnCompanyIdChanging(string value)
   {
     ValidateRequiredField("CompanyID", value);
   }

   private void OnCompanyNameChanging(string value)
   {
     ValidateRequiredField("CompanyName", value);
     ValidateFieldLength("CompanyName", value, 30);
   }
}
```

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: There's not an exception being raised inside the code.  Maybe the following will help illustrate:  bind the DbContext.Companies to a BindingSource inside the form, set the ErrorProvider's DataSource to the BindingSource, set the DataBindings property on the text boxes of the forms to the CompanyID, CompanyName properties.   If you navigate to a company that has a company ID and then attempt to remove the company ID, instead of receiving "CompanyID is required" in the ErrorProvider you'll receive "Input string was not in a recognized format".

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more research on this and testing out code samples I was able to find a solution to this particular item.  A custom TypeConverter was needed for a non-nullable integer conversion.  I was able to locate information [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/ec5e6a17-a0c5-43a8-bdc0-212b35ea5408/)
and ended up with the following TypeConverter for testing a "Required Integer":

```
public class RequiredIntConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode]
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("This field requires an integer value and cannot be blank.");
        }
        int result = 0;
        if (!int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out result))
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("The value could not be parsed as a valid integer data type.");
        }
        else
        {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

When I initially tested the code from the link above my debugger kept breaking when I attempted to throw the ApplicationException.  Thinking this was an error in my code I was confused on how to use the TypeConverter.  However, I found the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513577/c-sharp-pragma-to-suppress-break-on-thrown-error) which describes how to suppress the debugger from breaking on a method.

I'm still a bit unsure on why it breaks on this ApplicationException and how the ErrorProvider knows to display the underlying exception.  If anyone could point me to some additional resources on this it would be greatly appreciated.

Have a great day.